# How to acces derivated class if it is private

Tags: visual-c++

```
class Alpha
{
   private:
       int a,b;
   public:
       void Perimeter();
};
class Beta
{
   private:
       int x;
   public:
   void Area();
};
```

Comment: What's your question....?

Comment: In the code you show, no class is derived from any other class, whether privately or publicly. What do you have difficulty accessing from what else?

Comment: Sorry about that forgot to made Class beta public: Alpha now all I need is somehow to calculate in void Area(){ The b variable of class Alpha and the x of the class Beta both private}